# $T^{eq}$ is a complete $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose $T$ is a complete $\mathcal{L}$-theory with infinite models. Enumerate the collection of all $\emptyset$-definable equivalence relations modulo $T$ as $(E_\alpha(\overline{v}_1,\overline{v}_2))_{\alpha\in\lambda}$ for some cardinal $\lambda$, where each $E_\alpha$ is an equivalence relation on $n_\alpha$-tuples; we may assume $E_0$ is equality of one-tuples. Then we define $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ to be a $\lambda$-sorted language, with sorts $(S_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \lambda}$, and we refer to $S_0$ as the "home sort". $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ contains a symbol for every symbol $\mathcal{L}$, interpreted as acting on $S_0$. (So, eg, if $\mathcal{L}$ has an $n$-ary relation symbol $R$, then $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ has an $n$-ary relation symbol $R^{eq}$, defined on the sort $S_0$.) Also, for each $\alpha\in\lambda$, $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ has a function symbol $\pi_\alpha:S_0^{n_\alpha}\to S_{\alpha}$, considered to be the projection map taking a tuple to its equivalence class modulo $E_\alpha$.

In particular, every $\mathcal{L}$-sentence can be thought of as an $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-sentence in a natural way, by considering it as a statement about the $S_0$ sort. Then we define $T^{eq}$ to be the union of all these sentences with the additional axioms
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 &\bullet\forall (w\in S_{\alpha}) &&\exists (v_1\dots v_{n_\alpha}\in S_0) [w=\pi_\alpha(v_1,\dots,v_{n_\alpha})] \\
 &\bullet\forall(v^{(1)}_1,\dots,&&v^{(1)}_{n_\alpha}\in S_0)\forall(v_1^{(2)},\dots,v_{n_\alpha}^{(2)}\in S_0) \\ & &&[\pi_\alpha(v^{(1)}_1,\dots,v^{(1)}_{n_\alpha})=\pi_\alpha(v_1^{(2)},\dots,v_{n_\alpha}^{(2)})]\leftrightarrow E_\alpha\left(\overline{v^{(1)}},\overline{v^{(2)}}\right)
\end{alignat*}

for every $\alpha\in\lambda$. It is easy to see that $T^{eq}$ is consistent; take any $M$ a model of $T$, and interpret each $S_\alpha^M$ as the equivalence classes of $M^{n_\alpha}$ under $E_\alpha^M$, with $\pi_\alpha$ the canonical projection map. Now, the claim is that $T^{eq}$ is complete. This seems obvious to me, but the resource I'm using (Tent and Ziegler) doesn't include a proof, and the only proof I can come up with uses some machinery that seems like it shouldn't be necessary:

---

For an arbitrary language $\mathcal{L}$, we say that an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $M$ of cardinality $\kappa\geqslant\aleph_0$ is "special" if $M$ is the union of an elementary chain $(M_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\kappa}$, where each $M_\lambda$ is $\lambda^{+}$-saturated.

**Fact 1:** If two special $\mathcal{L}$-structures of cardinality $\kappa$ are elementarily equivalent, then they are isomorphic. $\square$

**Fact 2:** Let $M$ be any infinite $\mathcal{L}$-structure. Then, for any cardinal $\lambda$ with $\beth_\lambda>|M|$, there is a special elementary extension of $M$ of size $\beth_\lambda$. In particular, any $\mathcal{L}$-theory with infinite models has arbitrarily large special models. $\square$

---

**Lemma:** The $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-theory $T^{eq}$ is complete.

**Proof:** Let $T_1\supseteq T^{eq}$ and $T_2\supseteq T^{eq}$ be any complete $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ theories. By fact 2, there are special $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ structures $M_1\models T_1$ and $M_2\models T_2$ of the same cardinality.  By construction of $T^{eq}$, each $M_i$ can be considered as a model of $T$ in the natural way, by restricting attention to the $S_0$ sort. Reducts of $\mu$-saturated structures are $\mu$-saturated, so each $M_i$ is in fact a special $\mathcal{L}$-structure. Thus, since $T$ is complete and so $M_1$ and $M_2$ are elementarily equivalent $\mathcal{L}$-structures, by fact 1 there is an $\mathcal{L}$-isomorphism $f:M_1\to M_2$.

We claim we can extend $f$ to an $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ isomorphism $\overline{f}:M_1\to M_2$ by taking $$\overline{f}(\pi^{M_1}_\alpha(m_1,\dots,m_{n_\alpha}))=\pi_\alpha^{M_2}(f(m_1),\dots,f(m_{n_\alpha})).$$ Note that, since the $\pi_\alpha$ are surjective, this defines $\overline{f}$ on all of $S^{M_1}_\alpha$. Also, for all $\overline{m}$ and $\overline{m}'$, we have
\begin{align}
\pi^{M_1}_\alpha(m_1,&\dots,m_{n_\alpha})=\pi^{M_1}_\alpha(m'_1,\dots,m'_{n_\alpha}) \iff E^{M_1}_\alpha\left(\overline{m},\overline{m}'\right) \iff E^{M_2}_\alpha\left(f(\overline{m}),f(\overline{m}')\right) \\ 
&\iff \pi^{M_2}_\alpha(f(m_1),\dots,f(m_{n_\alpha}))=\pi^{M_2}_\alpha(f(m'_1),\dots,f(m'_{n_\alpha})).
\end{align}
The forward direction of this shows that $\overline{f}$ is well-defined, and the backwards direction shows that $\overline{f}$ is injective. To show that $\overline{f}$ is surjective, let $\pi^{M_2}_\alpha(m_1,\dots,m_{n_\alpha})\in S_\alpha^{M_2}$ be arbitrary. By surjectivity of $f$, there are $m'_1,\dots,m'_{n_\alpha}$ such that $f(\overline{m}')=\overline{m}$, and then $$\pi^{M_2}_\alpha(m_1,\dots,m_{n_\alpha})=\overline{f}(\pi^{M_1}_\alpha(m'_1,\dots,m'_{n_\alpha})),$$ as desired. Finally, $\overline{f}$ commutes with the $\pi_\alpha$ by construction and takes each $S_\alpha^{M_1}$ to $S_\alpha^{M_2}$, so it is in fact an $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$ isomorphism, and – in particular – $M_1$ and $M_2$ are elementarily equivalent as $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-structures. Thus $T_1=T_2$ and so $T^{eq}$ is itself complete, as desired. $\square$

---

Now, I have two questions. First, does this proof look right? Second, it seems to me that there should perhaps be a more immediate proof of the desired result. Special structures take a bit of effort to define (though no set-theoretic assumptions! in contrast with saturated structures); is there a more direct way of seeing the result?

Comment: It's a bit tedious, but: suppose $M,N\models T^{eq}$ with home sort reducts $M_0,N_0$. Since $T$ is complete we get $M_0\equiv N_0$. We now apply the Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game characterization of $\equiv$, and show how to "lift" a winning strategy for $\mathsf{Duplicator}$ in $EF_\omega(M_0,N_0)$ to a winning strategy for $\mathsf{Duplicator}$ in $EF_\omega(M,N)$ (it will help to consider the version of the game where players play tuples, as opposed to individual elements, of the structures in question). Writing out the details is annoying, but it removes the need to build saturated structures.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that makes sense, thank you! do you know of any references that take this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks fine, but you're right that there's a more elementary approach, not using special or saturated models, or EF-games.

1. Show that for any model $M\models T^{eq}$, we have $M = (M\restriction \mathcal{L})^{eq}$.
2. Show that $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-formulas can be "translated" back to $\mathcal{L}$-formulas in the following sense: Consider an $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-formula $\varphi(x;y_1.\dots,y_k)$, where $x$ is a tuple of variables from the home sort and the $y_i$ are single variables from the new sorts, say $y_i$ comes from the sort $S_{\alpha_i}$. Then there is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\bar{\varphi}(x;z_1,\dots,z_k)$, where each $z_i$ is a tuple of length $n_{\alpha_i}$, such that for any $M\models T$ and any tuples $a,c_1,\dots,c_k$ from $M$, we have $$M\models \bar{\varphi}(a;c_1,\dots,c_k)\iff M^{eq}\models \varphi(a;\pi_{\alpha_1}(c_1),\dots,\pi_{\alpha_k}(c_k)).$$
3. Now any two models of $T^{eq}$ can be written as $M^{eq}$ and $N^{eq}$ for $M$ and $N$ models of $T$. For any $\mathcal{L}^{eq}$-sentence $\varphi$, we have $$M^{eq}\models \varphi \iff M\models \bar{\varphi}\iff N\models \bar{\varphi}\iff N^{eq}\models \varphi$$ by completeness of $T$. So $T^{eq}$ is complete.

Point 2 is a bit tedious to write out carefully, but it's worth doing: this is the fundamental fact about the eq construction that makes everything else work.

Comment: that's a much simpler argument, thank you! p.s. this is a small question, but how is $T^{eq}$ pronounced? is it "eek" or "ee queue"?

Comment: Haha. A reasonable question! It's "Ee queue".